# Rails 5.2.0 associations work in RSpec, don't work in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a class

```
class Rule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :keyword_group, optional: true
```

that works great when I use it in RSpec. If I put in a `byebug` and check the associations:

```
(byebug) Rule.reflections["keyword_group"].foreign_key
"keyword_group_id"
```

but when I check from rails console:

```
> Rule.reflections["keyword_group"]
=> nil
```

Any thoughts on where this might be going wrong? All of my associations in other files work great in both RSpec and in `rails console`.

Comment: Try `reload!` in the `rails console`. Maybe you made the change after you started the `rails console` session

Comment: @AbM wow, thank you! `reload!` specifically didn't work, and I'd already restarted the console many times, but that reminded me about Spring. `spring stop` and restarting the console did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

`spring stop` and restarting the Rails console did the trick.

The root cause of the missing reflections turned out to be related to [Ruby on Rails Monkey Patching a Gem's Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994672/ruby-on-rails-monkey-patching-a-gems-model)