# Where to put custom Array methods or Enumerable methods in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have custom array methods like

```rb
class Array
  def decreasing?
    for i in (0...self.size)
      return false if self[i] > self[i+1]
    end
    true
  end

  def increasing?
    for i in (0...self.size)
      return false if self[i] < self[i+1]
    end
    true
  end
end
```

And

```rb
module Enumerable
  def sorted?
    each_cons(2).all? { |a, b| (a <=> b) <= 0 }
  end
end
```

Currently I have them in a model file randomly. Where is a better place to put these codes in Rails?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Monkey Patching in Rails 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420680/monkey-patching-in-rails-3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put it in an initializer (in `config/initializers`) called `array_extensions.rb` and `enumerable_extensions.rb`.

Comment: Why do you think that it doesn't belong to ````/lib````?

Comment: @Bob, I am not saying that it doesn't belong there. You said "it must be", but it *does not have to be*, as my answer shows. If you put it in `/lib` you have to `require` it first with initializers that's not necessary.

Comment: thanks) You can add ````lib```` to ```autoload_paths``` and it will be loaded)

Comment: Tested that both ways work, but using `config/initializers` was more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be under `/lib` directory.