# Carrier Wave Version Store URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I'm trying to setup the store_dir for the files being uploaded to carrier wave, but I want a particular url structure (like I had using paperclip). I have two versions :main and :thumb, but it seems that the url being store using model.id is /MODEl/ID/VERSION_IMAGENAME.FILETYPE. I am trying to figure out how to structure the url to be /MODEL/ID/VERSION/IMAGENAME.FILETYPE, but am not having any luck. Any help?

A sample url:

/event/1/main_IMG1922.JPG, but I would like to have /event/1/main/IMG1922.JPG.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this overriding the `full_filename` and `full_original_filename` methods as shown on this [carrierwave wiki page](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-To%3a-Move-version-name-to-end-of-filename,-instead-of-front)

Here's the example they show for changing filenames from `version_foo.jpg` to `foo_version.jpg`. Customize it to suit your needs.

```
module CarrierWave
  module Uploader
    module Versions
      def full_filename(for_file)
        parent_name = super(for_file)
        ext         = File.extname(parent_name)
        base_name   = parent_name.chomp(ext)
        [base_name, version_name].compact.join('_') + ext
      end

      def full_original_filename
        parent_name = super
        ext         = File.extname(parent_name)
        base_name   = parent_name.chomp(ext)
        [base_name, version_name].compact.join('_') + ext
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Would I create that file in an initializer. I can see making it work, but the wiki doesn't specify the file name or location to put a file that overwrites those methods.

Comment: WHERE to put files for monkey patching is debatable. But it should work in an initializer. Here's a related SO question/answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420680/monkey-patching-in-rails-3