# Monkey patching Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to monkey-patch one of the Rails core classes, specifically `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper::ClassMethods.link_to` method. As far as I remember there are some events fired when parts of Rails are loaded, how to add handlers for them? Or should I just put the code into initializer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Monkey Patching in Rails 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420680/monkey-patching-in-rails-3)

Answer (score 1):

`link_to` does not appear to be in ClassMethods. [From here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/64ce0918a6391db785fd4d95f121312bd0eb77df/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb#L451).

In `config/initializers/url_helper_extensions.rb`

```
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module UrlHelper
      alias_method :_link_to, :link_to
      def link_to

        # Your code ...

        # Call original method if you want.
        _link_to

      end
    end
  end
end
```