# Injecting values into all link_to method calls in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to, monkeypatching

I have a strange requirement that I need to inject a value at the beginning of all local links. This is a legacy app and is quite large so I'm looking to do it under the hood, maybe with a monkey patch.

Basically if I have a `link_to "Go to dashboard", dashboard_path` or `link_to "Create a new Job", new_job_path` that they would both generate links that look like "/some_value/dashboard" and "/some_value/jobs/new"

Tried a few things and they all have failed. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a static value or dynamic?

Comment: dynamic. it's coming from a param in the url. needs to just pass it along.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in your helper instead of monkey patching link_to.

```
 def custom_link_to(link, url, opts={})
    url = "append_here/"+url
    link_to(link, url, opts)
  end
```

Now you can call this action instead of calling link_to wherever applicable and also use link_to in case if you don't want to override.

```
custom_link_to("Go to Dashboard",dashboard_path,{})
```

**UPDATE**

In case of overriding everything, something similar to this might be helpful - [Monkey patching Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20465886/monkey-patching-rails)

Comment: problem with that is that we have 1000s of link_to methods that i don't want to have to update

Comment: For those links that you need not update, you can use the normal link_to tag right? Let me know If I am missing something @Jonathan

Comment: All the links have to have the value prepended to them. That's why I was looking to subclass or monkey patch.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Hope it help you @Jonathan